# Histogram from character string in R (from chr to num)

Tags: r

I'm a newbie in R and have been stuck with this problem for a long time now. Given how simple it seems, I'm puzzled to be stuck with this for so long. So here we go:

Basically, I have a vector, let's call it "test", which contains a series of numbers.

```
[1] "9 29 7 22 5 5 5 8 14 5 5 8 7 9 15 15 7 5 5 6 6 5 9 5 6 7 6 7 11 5 6 10 5 5 7 8 23 11 15 24 5 5 11 5 7 19 6 6 30 6 7 7 24 9 8 15 5 5 29 10 17 6 6 11 26 9 19 32 7 8 14 5 8 8 18 6 5 9 6 11 5 7 6 8 5 6 54 6 7 8 22 7 5 8 6 31 6 5 8 26 12 9 7 5 11 6 27 9 6 15 17 5 8 5 6 5 5 5 9 6 5 7 7 9 10 11 33 19 13 6 18 6 9 7 5 6 8 5 5 5 6 5 6 5 18 6 6 7 8 9 5 8 5 8 16 5 8 6 8 7 12 8 13 11 5 17 15 5 12 7 7 11 6 6 5 10 9 5 5 14 7 12 6 5 5 7 5 30 7 5 8 5 9 10 21 6 14 9 7 14 26 23 7 24 7 13 7 5 5 9 12 11 6 5 5 6 5 6 7 76 5 10 6 16 5 12 11 15 6 28 7 14 8 5 6 5 8 5 12 6 5 10 5 14 7 8 6 5 5 8 19 15 10 7 5 14 5 15 7 8 6 6 5 35 5 6 5 11 5 13 5 7 12 11 5 6 10 5 15 6 12 9 11 5 7 9 8 17 8 8 11 6 7 5 15 10 8 8 9 26,6 25 6 13 11 6 15 5 7 7 38 9 5 10 10 11 6 8 6 13 10 7 5 18 9 12 6 16 13 8 8 6 5 5 8 8 8 5 6 5 5 5 5 7 13 6 12 6 6 10 8 8 18 6 5 12 5 8 17 5 18 5 5 17 8 7 6 7 16 10 7 6 10 6 6 10 17 5 10 7 10 6 11 9 5 25 12 13 6 11 5"
```

R interprets this as a character string:

```
str(test)
chr "9 29 7 22 5 5 5 8 14 5 5 8 7 9 15 15 7 5 5 6 6 5 9 5 6 7 6 7 11 5 6 10 5 5 7 8 23 11 15 24 5 5 11 5 7 19 6 6 30..."
```

What I wish to do is no more complex than this: I would like to create a histogram, plotting the frequency of each number in the character string above (in fact, this is the degree distribution for a network).

The problem is that I'm dealing with a character string.

```
> hist(test)
Error in hist.default(test) : 'x' must be numeric
```

However, if I try to convert "test" into numeric, it also fails.

```
> as.numeric(test)
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

I'm sure the solution is something very simple here, but I've tried to search for a solution for a long time without success.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using stringr package to split character string into a list, then unlist and store as numeric vector:

```
a <- "9 29 7 22 5 5 5 8 14 5 5 8 7 9 15 15 7 5 5 6 6 5 9 5 6 7 6 7 11 5 6 10 5 5 7 8 23 11 15 24 5 5 11 5 7 19 6 6 30 6 7 7 24 9 8 15 5 5 29 10 17 6 6 11 26 9 19 32 7 8 14 5 8 8 18 6 5 9 6 11 5 7 6 8 5 6 54 6 7 8 22 7 5 8 6 31 6 5 8 26 12 9 7 5 11 6 27 9 6 15 17 5 8 5 6 5 5 5 9 6 5 7 7 9 10 11 33 19 13 6 18 6 9 7 5 6 8 5 5 5 6 5 6 5 18 6 6 7 8 9 5 8 5 8 16 5 8 6 8 7 12 8 13 11 5 17 15 5 12 7 7 11 6 6 5 10 9 5 5 14 7 12 6 5 5 7 5 30 7 5 8 5 9 10 21 6 14 9 7 14 26 23 7 24 7 13 7 5 5 9 12 11 6 5 5 6 5 6 7 76 5 10 6 16 5 12 11 15 6 28 7 14 8 5 6 5 8 5 12 6 5 10 5 14 7 8 6 5 5 8 19 15 10 7 5 14 5 15 7 8 6 6 5 35 5 6 5 11 5 13 5 7 12 11 5 6 10 5 15 6 12 9 11 5 7 9 8 17 8 8 11 6 7 5 15 10 8 8 9 26,6 25 6 13 11 6 15 5 7 7 38 9 5 10 10 11 6 8 6 13 10 7 5 18 9 12 6 16 13 8 8 6 5 5 8 8 8 5 6 5 5 5 5 7 13 6 12 6 6 10 8 8 18 6 5 12 5 8 17 5 18 5 5 17 8 7 6 7 16 10 7 6 10 6 6 10 17 5 10 7 10 6 11 9 5 25 12 13 6 11 5"

library(stringr)

b <- as.numeric( unlist ( str_split (a, " ")))

hist(b)
```

The histogram I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Note that before calling `library(stringr)`, you need to install the package by calling `install.packages("stringr")`

Comment: Perfect! I used this and it worked. Problem solved. :-)

Comment: @robocop great! please, accept the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 3):

The `str(test)` shows that is a single string, so we can extract the elements with `scan` and then use `hist`

```
hist(scan(text = test, what = numeric(), quiet = TRUE))
```

---

Upon looking at the OP's data, there are spaces and `,`.  So, we change it to a single delimiter and then use `scan`

```
hist(scan(text = gsub(",", " ", test), what = numeric(), quiet = TRUE))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your test "vector" is just one long string. 
A numeric vector is as follows:

```
nums <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

You could also make a character vector and convert it, like you tried:

```
chars <-  c("1","2","3","4","5","6")
nums <- as.numeric(chars)
```

Your values are more like:

```
char <- "1 2 3 4 5 6"
```

which cannot be converted to a numeric value with as.numeric(), as it is one long string rather than a vector of numbers or characters